# My AV rack (metal) is close to the grounding rod & my receiver/projector frequently get fried

Tags: electrical, grounding, home-theater

Dumb me ! my receiver/projector has been fried 3 times & I had tried everything:

- Called in an electrician
- Installed circuit breakers
- Cried..

But it kept getting fried ! And today when I was hooking my receiver up I saw that close to the nearby AC duct, **hidden behind it is the grounding rod** !!
It's the rebar with copper wire at the top, etc. & about 3 feet away from the cabinet.

**IMPORTANT:** The frying incidents have always happened during a storm. Hence lightning is the prime suspect.

Now I'm no electrician, but that seems to be the bloody problem !!!

So I need help in understanding what my options are:

- Move the cabinet as f#$#ing far - I can only go 5 feet due to placement & wall
- Ground my cabinet ? like a metal chain. One end tied to the cabinet, other on ground ?
- Place the cabinet on a wooden board
- Place the receiver on a some anti-static mat or insulation board ? Wood/rubber/etc.. ?

Please let me know your thoughts folks !

Comment: Grounding rod close by should not cause problems unless getting hit by lighting often.   Power surges and heat usually the two main causes of frying electronics.

Comment: Yes, important point - every frying incident has been during a storm. Hence I've also installed smart plugs this time, so I can it turn off if a storm comes. But that's a horrible solution which I don't want to rely on.

Comment: Say this 10 times: "Correlation is not causality".  Just because your problems happen during lightning storms does not mean grounding has anything to do with it.  It could be several other causes.  Also, how close it is to the ground rods doesn't matter. ESD won't jump several feet (or at least, not without leaving a big mess lol).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - You might be correct, but that doesn't mean I don't take any steps & keep performing the repairs either correct ? So I'm just trying to fix the most likely cause. If it doesn't fix the issue, I'll go for the second most probable cause next time.

Comment: I think @Harper-ReinstateMonica is telling you that your first thought (the ground bar) is not a likely cause. Crip659 has also shared that power surges and excessive heat are much more likely. Is your equipment behind a good quality surge protector? It the cabinet properly ventilated? You can do the things you've listed in your question and it will have zero benefit if power surges or excessive heat are the problem. I'd rule those potential causes out before worrying about the grounding.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If frying during storms, I would invest in surge protectors, either just for equipment or whole house.  Most power companies usually suggest unplugging electrical equipment during lighting storms, at least they use to.

Comment: I'm saying you are confusing "the most **likely** cause" with "the most **obvious** cause".  The problem is, that is constrained by the limits of your knowledge.  Which leaves out stuff, and the stuff left out could actually be the cause.

Comment: @crip659 - I didn't know manufacturers said that. Is there no way around it ? The equipment is in the basement, which is always a lot cooler even in peak heat, hence I doubt heat would be the cause. I'm replacing the existing surge protectors with 2 heavy duty Tripp-lite surge protectors, as another precaution.

Comment: Not manufacturers but power/electric companies, especially for power outages(everything coming on at once).  Was only a recommendation, don't even know if they still recommend it.  Manufacturers prefer you didn't, you buy their stuff again.

Comment: Tripp Lite used to have a replacement guarantee (limited to a certain amount of money) if a piece of equipment was damaged by a surge. If they still do, I would keep proof of purchase for both the surge protector and the equipment in case there's a claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grounding is almost never the enemy.

The ground rods being *nearby* has no bearing on the equipment.  Electricity doesn't know anything about paths it can't take.  It can't go even 1 foot through insulated materials and air without leaving a hell of a mess.  You would notice.

So I consider the nearby ground rods to be totally irrelevant to the issue.

Since the root of your problem is surges, I would address better surge suppression.

### Basic:

Quality surge suppressing power strips can be had from companies like Tripp-Lite.  Of course *most* power strips claim to be surge suppressors, but if you crack one open, you find there's not much there - just some MOVs, which are a type of voltage breakover device - they "breakover" (shortout) at 20-50% above normal line voltage, shorting out surges. However doing so shortens their life, that's why the boxes list the number of joules they can absorb (before the surge suppression is totally flat).

Better units like Tripp-Lite have more than MOVs.

They also make "whole house surge suppressors" which mount inside the breaker panel.

### Better:

An "isolation transformer".  Now here you have to be careful not to buy some mail-order garbage off the Amazon Marketplace, eBay, or other flaky channels - as the market is glutted with "step down transformers" and that's exactly what you *don't* want.

An isolation transformer provides total electrical isolation of the utility-side wires from the wires going to your equipment.  The hot-neutral coming from the utility (which might have surges that get past your surge suppression) do not connect to the isolated output.  Utility power is turned into a pulsing magnetic field at 60 Hz.  Transformers have an iron core tuned to pass 60 Hz efficiently. A spike comes along, and it contains very high frequencies - the iron core just won't pass it.  The transformer's secondary turns the magnetic field back into electricity, and your equipment uses it.

Make sure to have surge suppression on the source side to suppress anything from the utility that might otherwise arc across the transformer coils, and surge suppression on the sensitive equipment side to protect your precious *from each other*.  Because that happens.

Comment: Thanks Harper ! I got these https://amzn.to/3wJH6ng. These are plugged into the smart plugs so I can turn all equipment off during a storm. I hope these are good !

Comment: So I should ask the electrician to install an "isolation transformer" ? And where exactly should that be installed ?

Comment: @PlanetUnknown an isolation transformer can be a plug-in thing. It plugs into the wall and has sockets for the appliance(s).  The "smart plugs" are absolutely worthless for disconnecting to stop surges. Surges will hop right over the smart plug, and maybe even fry it as they pass.

Comment: A whole house surge protector installed in the main panel would be a good idea, not only for your electronics, but other devices as well. Your problem is almost certainly caused by powerful electromagnetically surges induced by lightning which a whole house surge protector would help contain...not fool proof, but a good step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks George - I had a full house surge protector installed after the first outage, but that hasn't helped. Called in the electrician again to make sure it's working & he said it is..